# Pattern matching to iterate over a list

Tags: list, haskell, logic

I am trying to learn Haskell from [Haskell Road to Logic](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~jve/HR/)
and came across this example:

```
    mnmInt :: [Int] -> Int
    mnmInt [] = error "empty list"·
    mnmInt [x] = x
    mnmInt (x:xs) = min x (mnmInt xs)
```

I understand the functions takes a list of `Int` -
Checks if empty
if not 
checks if it's a list with 1 int if so return x
if not
plug mnmInt with xs parameter to min.

how does it reach the base case? what does the xs stand for?

min implementation:

```
   min' :: Int -> Int -> Int
   min' x y | x <= y    = x
            | otherwise = y
```

doesn't take an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(x:xs)` is pattern matching syntax. Pattern matching lets you "destructure" data types and bind them to names. In this case x is the head of the list, and xs is the tail. `min'` doesn't need to take a list because x is the head of the list, not a list itself.

`min'` itself finds the minimum value between two `Ints`, `mnmInt` will eventually expand out to something like `(min' 1 (min' 2 (min' 3 4)))` if you pass in a list that looks like `[1,2,3,4]`.

This is easy to see if you evaluate the code by hand, which I highly suggest you try. Remember, `(x:xs)` is two names, which are the head and tail of the list. You might want to play around with constructing lists using `:`

Here is an example that shows how pattern matching relates to code flow.

```
foo (x:y:[]) = "two"
foo ([]) = "none"
foo (_) = "some other value"
```

if you call `foo [1,2]` it will output "two", if you do `foo [1,2,3]` it will give you "some other value", and if you do `foo []` it will return `"none"`

Comment: I understand the recursion. I guess I didn't get the pattern matching
matches each element separatly similar to grep. (or is it a regex thing?)

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure if you understood that. Pattern matching has nothing to do with regexes, although you can match against the results of a regular expression match by using `case`. It simply tries to look for a type that matches the pattern you write.

Comment: so the (x:xs) construction matches any list with a head and a tail?
If so - what expends the list? How does it know to iterate?

Comment: @raam86 Pattern matching matches values against the _constructors_ they're constructed with. Lists have the two constructors `[]` for the empty list and `(:)` which conses an element to a list. The pattern `(x:xs)` matches every nonempty list, `(x:y:zs)` matches lists with at least two elements.

Comment: Yes, if you input a list that has both a first element (`x` in this case) and a tail (so at least one more element), then it will call the code that you write for that pattern. Another pattern might be `[]` which matches an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a list in two ways in Haskell, first like [1,2,3,4,5], which is only syntactic sugar for 1:2:3:4:5:[].
Now the pattern (x:xs) matches with a list like this:

```
    head(x:xs) = x
    --> head [1,2,3,4,5] = head 1:2:3:4:5:[] = head 1:xs = 1
```

i hope this example make it clear to you how a list pattern works.